# how to display full text of a tweets in tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

hey guys i am using tweepy api to collect data from search where the word is pandemi and Indonesia but it seems that some of the tweets that i collect trunance with "...." or it just collect half of the tweets like ("my nam") can anyone shed some light? to fix this? thank you very much

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweets = [status._json for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="pandemi indonesia -filter:retweets",  lang="id", tweet_mode="extended").items(20)]
for tweet in tweets:
    d = tweet["full_text"].encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
    print(d)
```

Comment: If you're scraping with search terms, make sure you spell them correctly. 'pandemic'

Comment: my bad it suppose to be pandemi in the question because i want to search it base of my language in tweepy search

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to reproduce this. Can you try printing out the `id_str` field as well as the `full_text` field to identify a Tweet that is truncated the way you're describing? I'm seeing `full_text` fully expanded.

Comment: sorry to reply late but i already fix this it seems that the problem its not in the tweepy but in my csv file that not getting all the full_text of the tweets